# Boost.TypeErasure with forward declared type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-type-erasure

Recently, I try to use boost.type_erasure with forward declared type as shown below:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>

struct Type;

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest), Test, 1)

using Any = boost::type_erasure::any <
    boost::mpl::vector <
    HasTest<void(Type&)>,
    boost::type_erasure::destructible<>,
    boost::type_erasure::relaxed
    >
>;

int main() {
    Any obj;
}
```

However, the compiler (e.g. clang) complains about incomplete type:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_base_and_derived.hpp:228:42: error: incomplete type 'Type' used in type trait expression

    BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = (BOOST_IS_BASE_OF(B,D) && ! ::boost::is_same<ncvB,ncvD>::value));
```

Finally, I have to work around by changing the API from reference to pointer, i.e. replacing Type& with Type*.

**Problem:**

Is it possible to make the code above work?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mistakes in your code. First, the macro [`BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER`](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER.html%60) takes an argument for the number of arguments the member function takes. So you want:

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest), Test, 1)
```

Next, [`any`](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/type_erasure/any_Concept___idp305335072.html) is templated on a `Concept`, which can be a list of concepts. You forgot the list part, so you need:

```
using Any = any<boost::mpl::vector<
    HasTest<void(Type&)>,
    relaxed
    >>;
```

Otherwise, `relaxed` didn't get included in the `Concept` - which allows for default construction. Next, you didn't allow for destruction in your `any`, so you get compile errors on `~any()`. You need to additionally provide [`destructible<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/type_erasure/destructible.html).

And lastly, you can define your `Any` with a forward-declared type. It just must be complete by the type you use it. The following compiles:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/member.hpp>

namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
using namespace boost::type_erasure;

struct Type;

BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((HasTest), Test, 1)

using Any = any<mpl::vector<
    HasTest<void(Type&)>,
    relaxed,
    destructible<>
>>;

struct Type { };

int main() { 
    Any obj;
}
```

Comment: But you finally define Type... If it was pointer, I won't have to define it.

Comment: @cqdjyy01234 So use a pointer? Or you could file a bug report with Boost. Either way, the other bugs in your code still stand.

Comment: Yeah, I currently indeed use pointer. But, you know, pointer is not the best choice if reference is OK. Thanks for pointing out the bugs.